# Unity MouseWheel weapon change

Tags: unity, javascript, input, mouse

I am trying to make a simple weapon change in Unity3D. The best way to do this is with the mouse scroll wheel, as far as I can see.

I googled on how to do this and found that I have to use `Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")`; I use this piece of code and print it. Still, I always get an value of 0.
any ideas? I just need to solve how to get the value first, I'll figure out the rest myself.

Code idea:

```
function Update () {
    print(WeaponNumber);

    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")){
    WeaponNumber += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using the code you have above you need to configure the axis in the input manager and name it correctly.

The accepted answer here may be of help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/6106/implementing-the-scrollwheel

Comment: @BallzOfSteel, if you are satisfied with an answer, please click the accept answer button.